# Angular4: Nested ngFor loop radiobuttons - click selects every option

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Have an app, where i need the 3 x radio-buttons to be independently selected (as a filter functionality).

This is my html:

```
<div class="dropdown" *ngFor="let type of filterTypes">
    <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{{type}}</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu byrd-shade" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
      <div class="radio-group">
        <div class="checkbox-forms gay-flame-forms form-group radio">
          <label class="form-check-label">
              <div *ngFor="let media of filterMedia">
               <input *ngIf="filterMedia"
                      class="form-check-input"
                       type="radio"
                       name="filterMedia"
                       value="1">
               <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-circle"></i>{{media}}
             </div>
           </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

TS:

```
 filterTypes: any = ['Media type', 'License type', 'Verification'];
  filterMedia: any = ['All', 'Images', 'Videos'];
  filterLicense: any = ['All, Exclusive, Non-exclusive'];
  filterVerification: any = ['All', 'Verified', 'Non-verified'];
```

Output:

[image: 1] [image: 2]

Am i approaching this wrong? I need the radiobuttons to be singularly (?) active.

Comment: maybe i'm not understanding the issue clearly, i have creted this plunk and it's working fine [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/AYYyB8U3ntmQ14D8oYo1?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You are giving all the radio inputs same value, i.e. =1, then how will you distinguish between them. 
You should bind the value property to a variable depending on your loop iteration like below

```
 <div *ngFor="let media of filterMedia ; let i = index">
               <input *ngIf="filterMedia"
                      class="form-check-input"
                       type="radio"
                       name="filterMedia"
                       [value]="index">
               <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-circle"></i>{{media}}
  </div>
```

For three iterations of ngFor, it will create a radio with values 1,2, and 3.That should do the job.

Comment: Thats a valid point actually, but didnt fix my issue. The issue lies within the styling of the component apparently. My code is working with no styling, but as soon as i add a class to the tags, it makes the "select-all-radio"-thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the inputs in a form:

```
<div class="dropdown" *ngFor="let type of filterTypes">
<button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{{type}}</button>
<div class="dropdown-menu byrd-shade" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
  <div class="radio-group">
    <div class="checkbox-forms gay-flame-forms form-group radio">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <form>
          <div *ngFor="let media of filterMedia">
            <input 
            *ngIf="filterMedia" 
            class="form-check-input" 
            type="radio" 
            name="filterMedia" 
            value="1">
            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-circle"></i>{{media}}
          </div>
        </form>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hopefully I understood your question and this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you! I found, that the issue lied within the styling of the component apparently. My code is working with no styling, but as soon as i add a styling-class to the tags, it makes the "select-all-radio"-bug.